# How to Serialize context for Template::render

Tags: json, rust, handlebars.js, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I'm trying to use Handlebars with Rocket and Diesel. Unfortunately I didn't get this combination to work.

First I build a simple rest-API using [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-rest-api-in-rust-using-rocket-and-diese). Then I tried to test a handlebars-template without using the database-connection. This part works great.

Next I tried the same template with use of the database-connection. If I use the same methods as in the API for the context-part oft the Template, I get compiler messages which I don't understand. In case that the REST API uses JSON from serde, I expected that the output should be `Serialize`.

The faulty function:

```
#[get("/<id>")]
pub fn index(id: i32, connection: DbConn) -> Template
{
    let context = people::repository::index(id, &connection).map(|person| Json(person)).map_err(|error| error_status(error));
    Template::render("index", &context)
};
```

The struct:

```
#[derive(Queryable, AsChangeset, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[table_name = "people"]
pub struct Person {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub age: i32,
    pub profession: String,
    pub salary: i32,
};
```

The database query:

```
pub fn index(id: i32, connection: &PgConnection ) -> QueryResult<Person> {
    people::table.find(id).get_result::<Person>(connection)
}
```

I expect a successful compilation. The error messages are as follows:

```
[E0277] the trait bound `rocket_contrib::json::Json<people::Person>: people::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Person::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied. 
[Note] the trait `people::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Person::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `rocket_contrib::json::Json<people::Person>`
[E0277] the trait bound `rocket::http::Status: people::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Person::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied. 
[Note] the trait `people::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Person::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `rocket::http::Status`
```

Comment: This is probably not the solution; but I came across a similar issue recently on a project where I was using `serde_derive` crate instead of `serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}`

Comment: Hello u32i64, I'm using #[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive already in the main.rs file.